# javascript or jquery code to obtain entire text content of web page within an iframe (including/excluding links on that page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I know how to obtain the content of div within an iframe using jquery--

iframe content:

```
    <div id="myContent"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#myiframe").find("#myContent")
```

What I want to do is, obtain the entire text content of an iframe, both with the text of all links within that iframe, as well as text content excluding the link texts within that iframe.

I want to do this ideally using jquery, but pure js or jquery+ js is also fine with me.

Comment: have you tried with javascript **document.getElementById("myiframe").innerHtml**..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***[.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)***

```
<iframe src="your_url.com" id='myiframe'></iframe>
```

---

To get the whole content from iframe

```
$("#frameDemo").contents()
```

To get the data from specific element.

```
$("#myiframe").contents().find("#myContent")
```

Comment: In the code you have provided #myContent is mentioned-I want to obtain the content of entire page in iframe, not just content within a specific div named myContent? Is there some way to do this? If you know of such a way, then kindly edit and post that answer...Thanks,Arvind.

Comment: Subject of course to [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).